# Getting a 404 when trying to access Database Actions for my ADB with private endpoint

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am getting a 404 when trying to access Database Actions of an Autonomous Database with a private endpoint from my internal environment that is connected through VPN. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

All Autonomous Database tools are supported in databases configured with private endpoints, but additional configuration is required: to connect from your data center, to resolve the Autonomous Database private endpoint, you need a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN), mapping the private endpoint IP to the FQDN. For that you either need to add an entry into your client's hosts files (e.g. /etc/hosts on Linux) or you can use hybrid DNS in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure.

In addition to the name resolution, your dynamic routing gateway must allow the traffic to and from the Autonomous Database.

For what it's worth, if you want to learn more about the private endpoint setup, check [the official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/network-private-endpoint-notes.html#GUID-1EC9620B-9DB9-4E7B-B667-B3143FBDF7B2) and specifically [the connection example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/network-private-endpoint-examples.html#GUID-9F6401C4-6306-4212-88FD-95E536B730B1)